# How to get the data-esid attribute and POST?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

Everything works without `data-esid`, I can not send data in `data-esid`.

Where is the my error?

```
<a href="#" data-esid="123" data-lname="Saracoglu" onclick="goToWorld();">link1</a>
```

Javascript:

```
 function goToWorld() {
      var idno = $(this).data("esid"); 
      var last_name = $(this).data("lname");   
      var dataString = 'ESidNO='+idno+'&last_name='+last_name;

       $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           data:dataString,
           url:'Lib/Path/Page.php',
           success:function(data) {
               alert(data);
           }
       });
 return false;
 }
```

Comment: For accessing the "data-esid", you can use element.dataset.esid....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how this could work at all, with or without `esid`. The problem is that whatever `this` is in the context of your function, it is not the link you have clicked.

You are also not cancelling the click event, you return `false` but you are not using that value in your inline click handler. However, that would only cause the page to jump to the top as the link is `#`.

The easiest way to solve that is by attaching the handler to the link, using for example a class.

The result would be something like:

```
<a href="#" data-esid="123" data-lname="Saracoglu" class="goToWorld">link1</a>
```

javascript:

```
$('.goToWorld').on('click', function(e) {
      // Now $(this) is the link that was clicked
      var idno = $(this).data("esid"),
          last_name = $(this).data("lname");

      // Cancel the default click event
      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           data: {
                ESidNO: idno, 
                last_name: last_name
           },
           url: 'Lib/Path/Page.php',
           success: function(data) {
               alert(data);
           }
      });
});
```

Note that I have also replaced the data with an object so that the values will be properly escaped. That will not make a difference in the example code but it will when your values contain characters that have to be escaped in a url.

Comment: `var last_name` -> `var` You erased, why don't we need?

Comment: @Saracoglu You can comma-separate variables when you define them. I just did that out of habit...

Comment: If the result is successful, can I show a picture instead `alert`?

Comment: @Saracoglu Sure, you could add a picture with a class hidden for example and remove that class in the `success` function. Or add a completely new image.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass data in `{}`

instead your `dataString`, try this:

```
newData = {ESidNO: idno, last_name: last_name}
```